# What is the QBytearray, returned by QFile readAll()

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I want to ask that if the QFile().readAll () , returns a QByte Array then does it create a byte array on Physical memory or just provides a linked list address containing the positions of Bytes?.

can it create problem in the case of large files which are in GBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does create a byte array in RAM, copying the whole memory that is in your hard drive. So you will run into issues running `QFile::readAll()` on huge files.

The documentation for `QString QTextStream::readAll()` says:

> Reads the entire content of the stream, and returns it as a QString.
>   Avoid this function when working on large files, as it will consume a
>   significant amount of memory.

It is not mentioned for `QByteArray QIODevice::readAll()` (inherited by `QFile`), but it will be the same, since there is no way the pointers in a `QByteArray` can point somewhere in your hard disk (must be an address in the virtual memory allocated to the program by the OS, i.e. the stack or the heap).

Comment: But if the read() takes qint64 & returns a byteArray , So if it is taking qint64 length pointer so the resulting QByte array must be of length qint64  ... It means there must be a way to represent this Byte array from hard disk not from RAM....?

Comment: @Anupam, No, there are no way you can represent a byte array from your hard disk, since a C++ pointer must lie in the virtual memory allocated to your application. Hence, read() do copy the memory from your device (e.g., hard drive) to your RAM. A 64bit int is use since a 32bit int may not be enough for your needs. The largest 32bit int is around 4 billion, and maybe you would like to transfer 5GB from your device to your RAM. It would not be possible with a 32bit int.